# "no matching function for call error" when calling constructor from helper function in g++

Tags: c++, g++

I have a constructor

```
A::A(const Name& n,const IRole& r)
: ...
{ }
```

And helper function that uses the contructor

```
AP<A> A::Create(const Name& n, const IRole& r)
{
    return new A(n,r);
}
```

And g++ gives me error messages when I compile this code.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘AIR::AP<AIR::A>::AP(AIR::AP<AIR::A>)’
 note: candidates are:   AIR::AP<T>::AP(AIR::AP<U>&) [with U = AIR::A, T = AIR::A]
 note:                   AIR::AP<T>::AP(AIR::AP<T>&) [with T = AIR::A]
 note:                   AIR::AP<T>::AP(T*) [with T = AIR::A]
error:   initializing temporary from result of ‘AIR::AP<T>::AP(T*) [with T = AIR::A]’
```

What's wrong with this code?

### ADDED

```
AP<A> A::Create(const Name& n, const IRole& r)
{
    AP<A> port(new A(n,r));
    return port; 
}
```

Seems to solve this issue.

Comment: What's the definition of `AP`? And `A`? How are you calling `A::Create`?

Comment: The problem isn't with A's constructor, but with AP's (where there seems to be several, and the compilers cannot choose).

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing the call to `Create`; is that trying to copy the result of the call into a new variable?  Note that only non-const `AP<T>` objects can be copied, and so temporaries (which can't bind to non-const references) are not copyable with your current definitions.

Comment: Temporaries can bind to ref-to-const.

Comment: @Tomalak: Thanks for the comment -- I meant "non-const".